# Добавить значение ко всем полям в колонке

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно добавить значения ко всем полям в колонке в таблице.

Например у нас есть таблица `Items` с колонками `Id, Name, Descr,` в которой уже есть 500 записей.

Нужно обновить колонку `Descr` так, чтобы ко всем значениям добавилось слово `test`

Как то так

```
UPDATE Items i SET i.Descr = i.Descr + 'test';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE Items i SET i.Descr = i.Descr || 'test';
```

В oracle для арифметического сложения используется `+`, а для конкатенации (объединения) строк `||`

Comment: Можно воспользоваться функцией CONCAT
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php
Хотя не думаю, что велика разница.

Comment: Писать длиннее :)

Comment: Тоже верно, согласен)

Comment: @Mike, писать длинее, но зато всем будет понятно, даже тем кто не сильно знаком с особеностями Oracle. Да и код будет более переносимым для других систем.

Comment: @newman Ага, переносимым. в oracle у concat только 2 параметра. т.е. склеить 3 строки - только вложенными concat. В mysql, postgre, mssql concat принимает неограниченно параметров. в sqlite concat отсутствует. При этом `||` не работает в mysql и mssql, в остальных из вышеперечисленных СУБД работает. Так что получить тут хоть какую то совместимость нереально.

Comment: что то не работает. пишет, что значение слишком большое, хотя, если вручную добавить слово - работает. Может там цикл нужно? Чтобы во все колонки добавить слово?

Comment: @LocalUser Это значит что в какой то из записей не хватает места под добавляемую строку. вы же руками наверняка только в конкретную запись пробуете. а там могут быть значения и длиннее. дайте `select max(length(descr)) from items` и посмотрите насколько это значение близко к объявленному размеру колонки